# screen refreshing constantly when i get to this point in my game

Tags: qb64

in my game "The Dark/Lost Forest" Im Working on the part where you would get an ally and/or weapons, but when i go to that area, the text keeps refreshing, and i cant input any commands

Ive tried forcefully setting `check_1%` to `1` but that didnt work

```
smithery:

CLS

Saythis "As you walk into the smithery you notice swords, axes, hammers and tools used for forging are lining the walls, some newer than others but none of them have rusted or gone uncleaned, smith must care about his works, you also smell coals burning as you notice smith is flattening a rod of hot iron which looks like a sword,"
IF check_1% = 1 THEN PRINT "(1) Hello Smith, are the weapons I requested done?" ELSE PRINT "(1) Hello Smith, I would like to buy some weapons"
IF check_1% = 1 THEN PRINT "(2) Hello Smith, I would like to buy some weapons." ELSE PRINT "(2) Hello Smith, I would like to requst you to make some weapons."
PRINT "(3) Hey Smith, do you wanna joinme in my adventure?"
PRINT ""
PRINT "what will you do/say?"

SELECT CASE smithery$

    CASE "1"
        IF check_1% = 1 GOTO smithery1a ELSE GOTO smithery1b
    CASE "2"
        GOTO smithery2a
    CASE "3"
        GOTO smithery3a
    CASE ELSE
        GOTO smithery

END SELECT
```

what i want it to do is not refresh the screen like a mad man

i remebered why this happenes, i didnt add `input`

```
smithery:

CLS

Saythis "As you walk into the smithery you notice swords, axes, hammers and tools used for forging are lining the walls, some newer than others but none of them have rusted or gone uncleaned, smith must care about his works, you also smell coals burning as you notice smith is flattening a rod of hot iron which looks like a sword,"
IF check_1% = 1 THEN PRINT "(1) Hello Smith, are the weapons I requested done?" ELSE PRINT "(1) Hello Smith, I would like to buy some weapons"
IF check_1% = 1 THEN PRINT "(2) Hello Smith, I would like to buy some weapons." ELSE PRINT "(2) Hello Smith, I would like to requst you to make some weapons."
PRINT "(3) Hey Smith, do you wanna joinme in my adventure?"
PRINT ""
INPUT "what will you do/say?", smithery$

SELECT CASE smithery$

    CASE "1"
        IF check_1% = 1 GOTO smithery1a ELSE GOTO smithery1b
    CASE "2"
        GOTO smithery2a
    CASE "3"
        GOTO smithery3a
    CASE ELSE
        GOTO smithery

END SELECT
```

Comment: So i Forgot to add `input` so im going to see if that works

Comment: Could you update your post to describe these changes?

Comment: sorry im not on here often to check for replies, ill update it

Answer (score 1):

adding `input` worked, i usually forget to add that